# How to concat two list in java?

Tags: java, java-7

I want to replace the null values in list 1 by the values that corespand them from the same column of list 2, the result will be stored in list 3.

```
List<Date> list1 = Arrays.asList(opDate1, null, opDate2, null, opDate3);
List<Date> list2 = Arrays.asList(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5);
```

result :

```
List<Date> list3 = Arrays.asList(opDate1, date2, opDate2, date4, opDate3);
```

How should I proceed?

#### Update

My code :

```
public List<Date> concatList(List<Date> list1, List<Date> list2) {
    List<Date> list3 = new ArrayList<Date>();
    for(int i=0; i<list1.size();i++){
        for(int j=0; i<list2.size();j++){
        if(list1.get(i) == null)
            list3.add(list2.get(j));
        else
            list3.add(list1.get(i));
        }
    }
    return list3;
}
```

Comment: there can be a for loop to handle it. how would you attempt it?

Comment: see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0;i <list1.size();i++) {
    list3.add(list1.get(i) != null ? list1.get(i) : list2.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>(list1.size());
for (int i=0;i<list1.size();i++) {
    if (list1.get(i) == null) {
        list3.add(i,list2.get(i));
    } else {
        list3.add(i,list1.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to include some commentary with your code. Just good etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop. Within the loop, use an if statement. 
If the value at the specific point is null, replace it with the same location value from the other List

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
ListIterator<String> iter1 = list1.listIterator();
ListIterator<String> iter2 = list2.listIterator();
while(iter1.hasNext()) {
    String a = iter1.next();
    String b = iter2.next();
    if(a!=null) {
        list3.add(a);
    }
    else{
     list3.add(b);
    }
}
```

Since you need to access  each element, don't use list.get(i) for each i since that will give a complexity of O(n^2) rather than O(n)

Comment: Your if statement isn't gonna run.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it works

```
public List<Date> concatList(List<Date> list1, List<Date> list2) {
    List<Date> list3 = new ArrayList<Date>();

    /* here you will remove all null in your list*/
    list1.removeIf(Objects::isNull);   
    list2.removeIf(Objects::isNull);

    /* here you will add both list inside list3*/
    list3.addAll(list1);
    list3.addAll(list2);
}
```